# Jmeter JDBC Request Sampler with non-sql queries

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, nebula-graph

Is it possible to query non-sql requests with Jmeter JDBC Configuration?

I'm trying to load-test a nebula graphql instance using jmeter and have added the [nebula jdbc driver](https://github.com/nebula-contrib/nebula-jdbc) to the jmeter in order to configure the JDBC connection.

When I try to create a JDBC request in my test plan it only gives me the option to pick a SQL query type however nebula uses [Ngql](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/1.2.0/manual-EN/1.overview/1.concepts/2.nGQL-overview/) as it's querying language and not SQL. According to jmeter's [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) and [source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/AbstractJDBCTestElement.java) JDBC request can only accept SQL query types and queries.

Is there a way I can choose some other request type which will allow me to send Ngql queries with JDBC Connection using Jmeter? Or if someone was in the same boat as me and found a way around this Query type restrictio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw127.png)

Tried different query types and adding a custom query type to no use

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use JMeter's [JDBC Test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) due to [Auto Commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocommit) property which is mandatory in JMeter and which is not supported by Nebula

You can consider using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) for conducting the load, example code can be found in the [nebula java driver page](https://github.com/nebula-contrib/nebula-jdbc#example), just add necessary [import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) statements.